# How to make the drop down list to be defaulted for a user that have logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make the drop down list to be defaulted to the info provided by the user that have logged in, in this case the state he is from. Here is what I have so far. My code is really heavily tied together with each other that I'm not sure where I should show you where the code really is.

But I think its here:

```
$data['Kod_Penyu'] = makeSafe($_REQUEST['Kod_Penyu']);

if($data['Kod_Penyu'] == empty_lookup_value) {
    $data['Kod_Penyu'] = '';
}
$data['Negeri'] = makeSafe($_REQUEST['Negeri']);
if($data['Negeri'] == empty_lookup_value) {
    $data['Negeri'] = '';
}
$data['Daerah'] = makeSafe($_REQUEST['Daerah']);
if($data['Daerah'] == empty_lookup_value) {
    $data['Daerah'] = '';
}
$data['Kawasan'] = makeSafe($_REQUEST['Kawasan']);
if($data['Kawasan'] == empty_lookup_value) {
    $data['Kawasan'] = '';
}
$data['Pantai'] = makeSafe($_REQUEST['Pantai']);
if($data['Pantai'] == empty_lookup_value) {
    $data['Pantai'] = '';
}
```

Comment: How do u log in ur users?

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean by what my users hold, its their ownerID and groupID

Comment: when users successfully login do u save the user's data on a session or?

Comment: Yes, the user's data is saved on a session. And in MySQL database.

Comment: show me the sql query u did to fetch the countries from the db

Answer (score 0):

the code you showed isn't extracting data from database and because we don't know your table structure and your mysql class we can't right a proper answer ... an example code should be like :

```
    $data['Kod_Penyu'] = makeSafe($_REQUEST['Kod_Penyu']);
    if($data['Kod_Penyu'] == empty_lookup_value) { $data['Kod_Penyu'] = $row['Kod_Penyu']; } 
  $data['Negeri'] = makeSafe($_REQUEST['Negeri']);
            if($data['Negeri'] == empty_lookup_value){ $data['Negeri'] = $row['Negeri']; }
```